# What are alternatives for assert_options & ASSERT_CALLBACK

Tags: php, php-8.3

I have been using:

```
assert_options (ASSERT_CALLBACK, function(string $file, int $line, ?string $assertion, string $description = null){
    // my codes
}
```

However, [`assert_options`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.assert-options.php) has been deprecated as of PHP 8.3. What are other compatible alternatives to hook a function as default `assert` callback?

Comment: https://php.watch/versions/8.3/assert-multiple-deprecations - _"There are no replacements to mimic the functionality of assert.callback and assert.warning INI directives, which means calling custom callables and emitting PHP warnings is deprecated, and will not be possible in PHP 9.0 and later.

To enable or disable assert() calls, replace assert.active INI with zend.assertions INI directive."_

Answer (score 0):

Bard has surfaced a good alternative:

```
namespace my_ns;

function my_assert_handler(Throwable $e) {
  if ($e instanceof AssertionError) {
    // Your callback logic here
    echo "Assertion failed: " . $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
  }
}

set_exception_handler('my_ns\my_assert_handler');
```